# doctrine2 remove ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, doctrine, many-to-many, doctrine-orm

I have a Group Entity with the following class member and mapping:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinTable(name="groups_children",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 */
private $children;
```

Adding a child is trivial:

```
public function addChild(Group $group)
{
    if (! $this->hasChild($group)) {
        $this->children[] = $group;
        App::getEntityManager()->persist($this);
    }
}
```

Removing a child:

```
???????
```

How would I remove a child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Doctrine retrieves a list of values from a relationship, it uses an instance of [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/common/2.0/api) as opposed to a regular array.

ArrayCollection implements ArrayAccess, which means that `unset` works just fine.

However, an simpler way of doing it would be:

```
   $this->getChildren()->removeElement($child) // to remove by object
   $this->getChildren()->remove($index) // to remove by array index
```

Although, I'm a little confused with your current example. Why are you assuming that the Child id and Group id should be identical in the join table? And why in your adding example are you adding `$group` to the `$children[]` array? Don't mean to be critical, but it makes parsing your intention difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function removeChild(Group $group)
{
    foreach ($this->getChildren() as $key => $child)
    {
        if ($child->getId() == $group->getId())
            unset($this->children[$key]);
            break;
    }
}
```

This works. Is it the most efficient way though?

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayCollection::removeElement